# Getting information from two text documents in C#

Tags: c#, text

I'm making a program in C# where I want to to load two text documents into two string arrays(**wordlist.txt** and **dict.txt**).

The **wordlist.txt** file contains 10 lines that have one word on each line and the **dict.txt** contains 10 lines with one sentence on each line. I want to make it so that each when the user enters a word that exists on line 4 in **wordlist.txt**, the program shows a sentence on the corresponding line number in **dict.txt**.

How can I accomplish this? Please help!

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: what do you mean with `exists online`?

Comment: I meant exists on line 4 as in the line number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load both files in an array using `File.ReadAllLines`. First array will have words and second will have sentences.
2. Once you have the arrays, create a dictionary (assuming words are unique here).
3. Display dictionary value using user input as key.

Here is sample for doing #2. Rest, IMHO, is trivial.

```
List<string> words; // Create using ReadAllLines and then call ToList.
string[] sentences; // Create in #1

        Dictionary<string, string> map = words.ToDictionary(x => x, x => sentences[words.IndexOf(x)]);
```